# Retrieve next row in pandas dataframe / multiple list comprehension outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a Pandas dataframe, `wt`, with a datetime index and three columns as well as dataframe `t` with the same datetime index and three other columns below:

***wt***

```
date    0   1   2
2004-11-19  0.2 0.3 0.5
2004-11-22  0.0 0.0 0.0
2004-11-23  0.0 0.0 0.0
2004-11-24  0.0 0.0 0.0
2004-11-26  0.0 0.0 0.0
2004-11-29  0.0 0.0 0.0
2004-11-30  0.0 0.0 0.0
```

***t***

```
date    GLD SPY TLT
2004-11-19  0.009013068949977443    -0.011116725618999457   -0.007980218051028332
2004-11-22  0.0037963376507370583   0.004769204564810003    0.005211874008610895
2004-11-23  -0.00444938820912133    0.0015256823190370472   0.0012398557258792575
2004-11-24  0.006703910614525022    0.0023696682464455776   0.0
2004-11-26  0.005327413984461682    -0.0007598784194529085  -0.00652932567826181
2004-11-29  0.002428792227864962    -0.004562737642585524   -0.010651558073654366
2004-11-30  -0.006167400881057272   0.0006790595025889523   -0.004237773450922022
2004-12-01  0.005762411347517871    0.011366528119433505    -0.0015527950310557648
```

I'm currently using the Pandas `iterrrows` method to run through each row for processing, and as a first step, I check if the row entries are non-zero, as below:

```
for dt, row in t.iterrows():
    if sum(wt.loc[dt]) <= 0:
        ...
```

Based on this, I'd like to assign values to dataframe `wt` if non-zero values don't currently exist.  **How can I retrieve the next row for a given `dt` entry (eg, '11/22/2004' for `dt` = '11/19/2004')?**

**Part 2**

As an addendum, I'm setting this up using a for loop for testing but would like to use list comprehension once complete.  Processing will return the `wt` dataframe described above, as well as an intermediate, secondary dataframe again with datetime index and a single column (sample below):

***r***

```
date    r
2004-11-19  0.030202
2004-11-22  -0.01047
2004-11-23  0.002456
2004-11-24  -0.01274
2004-11-26  0.00928
```

**Is there a way to use list comprehensions to return both the above `wt` and this `r` dataframes without simply creating two separate comprehensions?**

***Edit***

I was able to get desired results by changing my approach, so adding for clarification (referenced dataframes are as described above).  **Wonder if there's any way to apply list comprehensions for this.**

```
r = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ret'],index=wt.index.copy())
dts = wt.reset_index().date

for i, dt in enumerate(dts):
    
    row = t.loc[dt]
    dt_1 = dts.shift(-1).iloc[i]   
    
    try:
       wt.loc[dt_1] = ((wt.loc[dt].tolist() * (1+row)).transpose() / np.dot(wt.loc[dt].tolist(), (1+row))).tolist()
       r.loc[dt] = np.dot(wt.loc[dt], row)  
                      
    except:
        print(f'Error calculating for date {dt}')   
        continue
```

Comment: `dt.shift(-1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, nah, had tried that; `shift` shifts the dataframe data, not the index values.  applying to the index itself requires a 'freq' param that doesn't correspond to entries in the index itself

Comment: You need to use shift() as @Quang Hoang suggested. This works fine for me: `df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.date)).shift()`, unless this is not what you mean.

Comment: @alibakhtiari, must not be explaining myself well.  `shift()` shifts the dataframe data, leaving the date index in tact, so doesn't address my issue.  have updated the question with a sample that returns what I want a slightly diff way for illustration.

Comment: `wt.index.to_series().shift()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, thanks.  That would get me there...prob going to leave with current implementation though.